# NOT ABLE TO SLIDE AS PDF

Tags: beamer

```
\documentclass[xcolor=dvipsnames,table]{beamer}
\usepackage{latexsym}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
%\usepackage[brazil]{babel}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{stmaryrd}
\usepackage{fancybox}
\usepackage{datetime}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{graphics}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{algorithmic}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{acronym}
\usepackage{array}

\newtheorem{definicao}{Definio}
\newcommand{\tab}{\hspace*{2em}}

\mode<presentation>
{
  \definecolor{colortexto}{RGB}{0,0,0}
 
  \setbeamertemplate{background canvas}[vertical shading][ bottom=white!10,top=white!10]
  \setbeamercolor{normal text}{fg=colortexto} 

  \usetheme{Warsaw}
}

\title{PROBLEMS} 


  \author[Mr. K \\ \url{.edu@gmail.com}]{\includegraphics[height=1.5cm,width=1.5cm]{kte.jpg}\\Mr \\ \url{.edu@gmail.com}}
 \institute{
  K \\Ho C}
\date{\textbf{\today}

 }
```

Hello! Please help me out.

I used the above code for my slide. The problem is when I extracted the file.pdf as a slide, I couldn't show slide by slide smoothly as powerpoint. Please I need it urgently.

Thank You so much!

Comment: Welcome! Did you change the setting on the pdf reader to single page display?

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding your problem.  What do you mean by "extracting as a slide"?  What do you mean by "smoothly"?  I'm not seeing any `frame` in your document;  what are you wanting to be displayed?  To elaborate on the problem mentioned by laura_b, most pdfs often open with the option to smoothly scroll the document, so that you end up being able to see the end of one page and the beginning of the next at the same time.  But you can change that option to "display mode" so that you only see one page at a time.